# Connecting to Mongo DB on GCE instance

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine

I have a Google Compute Engine instance which is running an active MongoDB server. I can connect to and interact with the server on the local machine via SSH.

However, when I attempt to connect to the database instance from an external source, like my home computer, I'm getting a connection refused. I have setup a firewall rule on the `default` network that looks like this:

```
Source Ranges:
0.0.0.0/0
Allowed Protocols or Ports:
tcp:27017
udp:27017
```

However, even after adding this rule to the `default` network I am still getting a connection refused when running:

```
$ mongo [ipaddress]
```

I'm not sure why the instance is refusing the incoming connection.

Comment: How did you install MongoDB? If you installed a packaged version of MongoDB 2.6 it's likely that the [`bindIp` parameter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) is set to only listen to requests on localhost. You need to change this to 0.0.0.0 or a comma-separated list of IP(s) you want `mongod` to listen on.

Comment: That sounds promising. I did install it as a package at version 2.6.5. I did a preliminary search, but I couldn't find where the default configuration file would be. Do you happen to know?

Comment: Assuming a [packaged install on Linux](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/install-on-linux/), the config file should be `/etc/mongodb.conf`.

Comment: That's the first place I looked and it wasn't there. This host system is running the Backports Debian 7 image available from GCE. Can I create this file and JUST fill in the bindIp property and then pass it to the mongo daemon and have it work fine or do I need to pass a full configuration file to avoid issues?

Comment: You can create a configuration file that only includes the defaults you want to override, but there must be an existing config file if `bindIp` is your issue. The default `bindIp` value is 0.0.0.0 (or "listen to all IP addresses"). Try `ps | grep mongod` to find the config file path for your running `mongod` instance, or run `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` in the `mongo` shell.

Comment: Ah, it's /etc/mongod.conf. I got it working now, if you submit a solution to edit that file I'll accept your answer.